# ckeditor replace textarea using class name with different toolbar confogurations

Tags: ckeditor

I am using the following code to add ckeditor to my pages.

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1"></textarea>
```

I would like to define a few toolbar configurations as not all of the textareas in my application need a full toolbar.
I have customized the default toolbar configuration for my needs, but would like to break this down even further to a more basic toolbar for some of my textareas.

Is there a way to do this if I am using the class attribute to set ckeditor?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to have different configurations for editors created by class name. In such case, only the global `CKEDITOR.config` is considered.

Still there's easy workaround for this problem. First, put this script in the top of the document:

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replaceClass = null; // Disable replacing by class
</script>
```

Now define the `data-custom-config` property (as [config.customConfig](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-customConfig)) for each `<textarea>` you want to replace like this:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" data-custom-config="myCustomConfig.js">
    Moo
</textarea>
```

Finally use the following code to manually replace editors by class name (assuming your class is `ckeditor`). This code will replace all textareas of the class `ckeditor` with CKEditor instance driven by the config defined in `data-custom-config` attribute:

```
var textareas = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementsByClassName( 'ckeditor' ) ),
    textarea, cfg, customCfg;

while ( ( textarea = textareas.pop() ) ) {
    textarea = new CKEDITOR.dom.element( textarea );
    cfg = {};

    if ( ( customCfg = textarea.getAttribute( 'data-custom-config' ) ) )
       cfg[ 'customConfig' ] = customCfg;

    CKEDITOR.replace( textarea.getId(), cfg )
}
```

And now comes the cherry on the top. Put your custom toolbar config in `myCustomConfig.js`:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbar = [
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic' ] }
    ];
};
```

Of course you can modify this code to involve jQuery for easier element selection, use some object literal instead of `config.customConfig` and so on. This is just a showcase of how the problem can be solved.